# Any efficient way to solve this fixed-rank problem?

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-rank, non-convex-optimization

My problem can be listed as follows:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f(X)\\ \text{subject to} & \mbox{rank} (X) = 3\end{array}$$

Is there some efficient algorithm to solve this problem? High complexity is affordable for high performance. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe state the whole problem? What is f?

Comment: such as $f=|Y - BX|_F^2$, where Y and B is known matrix

Answer (score 3):

The constraint $\mbox{rank}(X)=3$ is a non-convex constraint, so your optimization problem is in general non-convex.

One common approach to dealing with this is reparameterize the rank-3 matrix $X$ as

$X=VV^{T}$

where $V$ is an $n$ by $3$ matrix.  When you do this, you'll get rid of the nonconvex constraint, but you'll probably create a situation in which the new function of $V$ is nonconvex.

There are also methods that work directly with the rank constraint to find a local minimum solution.  Look for research on optimization on manifolds.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I have tried to use the manopt to solve this problem, however, in my problem the $X$ is a complex matrix, while it seems the manifold tools propsoed by manopt can only work for real matrix.

Comment: According to its documentation, the MATLAB package manopt supports a Stiefel manifold on complex matrices.